# Custom Resolution of Spring Beans

Tags: spring

I have a class hierarchy in which the top-level interface or any of the concrete implementations may be requested for injection. This particular area of code is dominated by autowiring, so beans are not bound by name - just class.

What I would like to do is avoid the use of specifying a bean name or using a Qualifier when a concrete implementation is requested. This is a rather unique situation where the class is descriptive of the usage context and only one of that class will be available. Is there a way to hook into Spring's bean resolution mechanism in order to tell it which bean to use? As it stands now, it finds x+1 valid matches where x are the parent classes in the class hierarchy.

It appears to me that the best way to accomplish this is to use CustomAutowireConfigurer to set my own AutowireCandidateResolver on all BeanFactorys. Is there a different FactoryBean implementation that would be easier? I'd basically like to see a DependencyDescriptor before deciding which bean to return.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a straightforward `FactoryBean`:

```
public class XyzFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<TopLevelInterface> {

    @Override
    public TopLevelInterface getObject() throws Exception {

        if( life is good ) {
            return new LifeIsGood();
        } else
            return new LifeIsBetterThanGood();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends TopLevelInterface> getObjectType() {

        if( life is good ) {
            return LifeIsGood.class;
        } else
            return LifeIsBetterThanGood.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```